# Cannot refer to my enum with import static java

Tags: java, static, enums

I have a hard time referring to my enum from `import static`.

Every file in the program is in a package.

Enum file:

```
package my.program;

public enum MyEnum {
   A,
   B,
   C;

   public static boolean aMethod (MyEnum e) {
      return something; //nevermind this returnvalue.
   }
}
```

And the file who is importing this:

```
package my.program;
import static my.program.MyEnum.*;

public class MyClass {

   public static void someMethod() {
      MyEnum e;
      if ( aMethod(e) ) {
         // doing something
      }
   }
}
```

So I want to make this `MyEnum e;` in `MyClass`, so that I may give `e` as parameter to `aMethod`. But when I do this I get compiler error:

```
cannot find symbol
class MyEnum
```

Note: this enum has maaany more attributes in the actual program. So I am not supposed to specify a certain attribute in `someMethod`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is your enum in a package? Where is the source for it? How are you trying to compile your code? (I'd *strongly* encourage you to follow Java naming conventions, by the way.) It would help if you'd provide a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem rather than this pseudo-code.

Comment: Yes, the whole program is in a package. I'll specify this in my Q :)

Comment: You cannot refer to a class in the default package.  If the class is in the same package, it still needs to the full name.  Your IDE should be able to correct this for you.

Comment: As a note, since Java `enum`s are classes, they should be named using the Java convention of an initial capital letter to avoid confusion.

Comment: If every class in your real code is in a package, why are your *sample* classes not in a package? Again, please show a short but complete program which is representative of your actual code (in terms of imports and class layout) rather than this pseudo-code which uses methods that don't exist and tries to pass an uninitiliazed local variable as an argument.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll be sure to do that from now on. Thanks for the notice.

Comment: Why not do it *now*? That would make your question more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import static package.myEnum.*;` imports constants of your `enum` (that is, allows you to access them by short names, such as `A`), but not the `enum` itself (so, you have to write `package.myEnum` to access the `enum`).

You also need `import package.myEnum;` to be able to refer to your `enum` as `myEnum`.

Comment: In fact that's all you need. You don't send the 'import static' at all.

Comment: The `import static` needed if you want to refer to `A` instead of `MyEnum.A`. I generally prefer to include the type for readability, but the OP's question had the enum values imported.

Comment: You aren't doing that in the code you posted, and you can do it anyway in a switch statement.

Comment: And this is why it's important to know that the enum is in a package - because if it were actually in the default package (or in the same package as the code using it), there'd be no need for an import at all.